# C++ quadratic congruential generator

Tags: c++, random

I'm rather new to C++ and I'm trying to implement a simple quadratic congruential random number generator. It seems to work alright but when I test it's period (repeat interval) it doesn't seem to repeat at all. I store the first random number in a variable and then compare the new numbers until the first one is encountered again, and this comparison doesn't ever get triggered. Is my if-statement wrong somehow? Apologies if this is about a stupid bug I can't see.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class QCG {
public:
    int seed;
    int m;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    QCG(int seed) {
        seed = seed;
        m = 1162261467;
        a = 14348907;
        b = 14348908;
        c = 65536;
    }

    int rand() {
        seed = (a*(int)pow(seed, 2) + b*seed + c) % m;
        return seed;
    }
};

//testing repeat interval
int main() {
    QCG qcg(1);

    //generate the first number and store it
    int first = qcg.rand();
    int i = 1;

    while (true) {
        //this gets triggered when the first value is reached again, i.e. when the period is completed
        if (qcg.rand() == first) {
            std::cout << "success! period is " << i << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        //this gets triggered if the previous condition isn't met by the maximum possible period
        if (i == 1162261468) {
            std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
            break;            
        }
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More than likely `seed = (a*(int)pow(seed, 2) + b*seed + c) % m;` is causing signed integer overflow which is undefined behavior (before C++20).

Comment: A good guess, but when I switched everything to using long int it didn't help. It seems like maniek's answer below is the issue.

Comment: depending on your system, `long int` can be the same size as `int`.  You can try `long long` but that's still signed so it is susceptible.  An `unsigned long long` might work for you.

Comment: use unsigned integers for defined overflow behaviour and avoid std::pow for raising integers to power so that it happens in integer domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes in a 'rho' shape - first there are some unique numbers, then there is a loop. It doesn't loop back to the first number, but to some further number. Look up Pollard's rho algorithm, or Brent's cycle detection algorithm

Comment: Thank you for the pointers! Looks like there's way more to random number generation than I thought.

Comment: Turns out I could fix the partial looping issue and obtain the full period by selecting the parameters more carefully using [these](http://statmath.wu.ac.at/software/prng/doc/prng.html#QCG) steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set your `first` random number as any one of repeated numbers in cycles. It could not go back to the first number directly generated from the `seed`, because the step size is not fixed and the modulus is a prime number.

However, there will eventually be cycles of repeated numbers, even though a cycle does not contain all integers less than the modulus.

```
    ...
    int first = qcg.rand();
    for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
        first = qcg.rand();
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
        ...
```

In this way, you can make it sure there is the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

We've known since the days of von Neumann's "[middle-square method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-square_method)" that while all PRNGs eventually cycle, some can contain multiple sub-cycles of different lengths.  This is nicely demonstrated in the [directed graph side image linked here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Middle_square_method_2_digits.svg).  As you can see there, and as @maniek pointed out, there can be subsequences that lead to a cycle but whose values are not within the actual cycle.  Wikipedia offers several [cycle detection algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection), with implementations in Python.

A PRNG which doesn't have sub-cyclic behavior, i.e., it produces every possible state before repeating, is called a "full cycle" generator.  PRNG testing tends to focus more on the existence of subcycles (proving that the generator is not full cycle) rather than the length of the cycle itself, which can be as small as 1.

This is further complicated by the observations in a [paper from the 1980's](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167637786900921), which noted that true randomness produces duplicate values without reproducing the sequence from that point forward. That concept led to a test showing that a full cycle PRNG producing values in the range (0, 2<sup>k</sup>) which doesn't produce any duplicates within 3*2<sup>k/2</sup> observations is provably non-random at an α=0.01 level.  In other words, if you were generating 32 bit integers but hadn't seen any duplicates within the first 200,000 values, an observer could declare the sequence to be non-random with probability > 0.99.  As a result, modern PRNGs use a much larger full cycle internal state space, which they collapse to produce a 32 or 64 bit output.  This produces duplicate values without leading to a duplicate sequence.